# Как сформировать http адрес для перехода к конкретному изменению конкретного коммита в GitLab

Tags: https, gitlab

Необходимо из 1С переходить по ссылке на конкретное изменение (в идеале до номера строки) определенного коммита. Через API получаю данные изменений в коммите. формирую в ИБ необходимые структуры и далее в отчетности по изменениям вижу какие объекты были изменены и хочу добавить к этим изменениям ссылку, чтобы пользователь в поле HTML документа смог (при наличии доступа, естественно) открыть интерфейс GitLab сразу на искомом изменении. Пока нашел только адрес коммита в репозитории, детализировать в адресе не получается, прошу помощи.

Comment: кнопка копи пермалинк

Comment: Боюсь таким образом можно получить ссылку на конкретный файл непосредственно с актуальным состоянием на момент указанного коммита, но без подсвеченных изменений. Мне же необходимо получить ссылку на файл с отображением изменений в рамках коммита. То есть как в интерфейсе просмотра изменений в коммите, файлы с указанными изменениями (+-).

Comment: Пока получилось детализировать ссылку до файла с изменениями в коммите. [Здесь](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/generating-a-link-to-the-compare-diff-result-of-a-single-file/55921) указан вариант решения. К ссылке на коммит через '#' добавляется sha1sum пути файла в репозитории, причем корнем в этом пути считается папка репозитория и путь до файл прописывается относительно нее. Если вам необходимо сформировать ссылку на файл *file1* с изменениями в коммите и файл находится в репозитории по адресу /myfiles/file1, то необходимо вычислить `$ echo -n myfiles/file1 | sha1sum` и добавить хеш к адресу.